# Axios data is breaking the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have an [express](http://expressjs.com/) API and a [ReactJs](https://reactjs.org/) front-end. I try to make a POST call from my front-end directly to the local API.

For this I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

The request is working fine when I set the parameters directly inside the query string but is always getting on timeout if I try to add the parameters through the `data` attribute of the `axios.post()` method.

**Working**

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:5001/site/authenticate?username=demo&password=demo`)
```

**Not working**

```
const payload = {
    "username":"mh",
    "password":"mh"
}
axios.post(`http://localhost:5001/site/authenticate`, payload)
```

My express server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.API_PORT || 5001;

app.use(cors());
app.set('secret', process.env.API_SECRET);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let data = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
});

// Allow CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// SITE ROUTES -------------------
const siteRoutes = express.Router(); 

siteRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    console.log('auth');
    getDocument(usersBucket, req.query.username)
        .then((doc) => {
            console.log("Authentification... TODO");

            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({
                success: true,
                status: 200,
                token: token
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Authentification failed. User not found.' });
        });
});

// route middleware to verify a token
siteRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('secret'), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.', status: 401 });       
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
    });

  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });
  }
});

siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome!' });
});

app.use('/site', siteRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
    logger.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Any idea? Thanks.

#### Update

I replaced my route just to see if I got in or not (without worrying about parameters):

```
siteRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    console.log("go in");
    res.json({
        success: true,
        status: 200,
    });
});
```

But my `console.log` is not showing hen I use the payload (it is when I do not).

Answer (score 2):

You should access the `payload` data via `request.body`, not the `request.query`:

```
// SITE ROUTES -------------------
const siteRoutes = express.Router(); 

siteRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    console.log('auth');
    getDocument(usersBucket, req.body.username) // <------- HERE
        .then((doc) => {
            console.log("Authentification... TODO");

            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({
                success: true,
                status: 200,
                token: token
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Authentification failed. User not found.' });
        });
});
```

`request.query` are the parameters passed in the URL, like:

```
protocol://hostname:port/path/to.route?query_param_0=value_0&query_param_1=value_1
```

on your express endpoint `request.query` will be:

```
{ 
  query_param_0: value_0,
  query_param_1: value_1
}
```

while sending the `payload`, with the [second argument in `axios.post(url, payload)`](https://github.com/axios/axios#example):

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
```

on your express endpoint `request.body` will be:

```
{
  firstName: 'Fred',
  lastName: 'Flintstone'
}
```

when you use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` (and you do).

Comment: Thank you, in fact I should use `req.body` but I don't think this is the source of the problem. As you can see in the update of my question, my request don't even go into my express route when using the payload. Any thought on that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using “getDocument(usersBucket, req.query.username)”

This means you express route is expecting username as a request param. That’s why it’s working when you use “?username=xx”

Instead try to get it from json body of request. 
“req.body.username”

Also you should consider validating the request body or param as required.

Comment: What do you mean by "validating the request body or param as required"? I did not copy the function that is checking the user is existing in the database and that hash passwords because I thought it was not relevant for my issue.